# Download a Android library from Github to IntelliJ Idea

Tags: android, github, intellij-idea, android-library

Is it possible to download an Android Library from Github directly into an Android project in IntelliJ Idea 12?

Comment: Do you mean sources checkout or download jar file?

Comment: I mean downloading jar and Android Library Project [http://pages.citebite.com/i8b6n9t5ownw]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should work for sources of the library project, perform a checkout under the project directory, then configure a new module for this directory with Android facet and **Is Library Project** option enabled, then add this module as a [dependency](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/configuring-module-dependencies-and-libraries.html) to your main application.

Answer (score 1):

You can download an Android Library directly into your build by using [JitPack](https://jitpack.io). Basically you tell it which repository you want and it will build it for you. Once its built you can use the library as a dependency.

If you are using gradle then you'd add this to build.gradle:

```
repositories {
    maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.github.Owner:Repository:Version'
}
```

You can also enter the github repo url on the jitpack.io website and it will give you the dependency to paste in your build file.